# How show an full screen image in a seperate viewcontrller from a small image in webviewer (like facebook)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-4.2, ios4

HI stackoverflow friends

I have an web app in iphone ,in which a lots of small images are loaded from webserver in a webview ,when I click on the image the image opens in a new viewcontroller with a navigation like facebook. How can I do this? give me some ideas and some sample codes.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

First place the images in your html(php) like this:

```
echo "<a class='yourButton' href='inapp://".$image."'><img src="image.png"></a>";
```

where `$image`=path to image.

Then in `webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest` put this:

```
if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"inapp"]) {
        NSString *fullUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://DOMAIN.com/%@",request.URL.host];

 NSURL *imgpath = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fullUrl];

            return NO;
      }
```

So the above will return `imgpath` which is the full url of the image when a user clicks on it. After that you will have to load a new viewcontroller with a imageview inside it,download the image with AFNetworking(http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/) and load the image in the imageview:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

All the above are written in memory so adjust your code properly.I am implementing the exact solution and i will post a full working code.
BTW,this could be my first ever accepted answer in Stack!